# Grails Integrationtest - Request Object

Tags: grails, request, integration

I'm testing a controller and there I defined an action which uses a value from the requestobject.

How can I mock the request object in an integration test?

I know that integration tests don't run in an Servlet, so there is no Requestobject, but how do I obtain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest thing is to mock needed methods using [Map coercion](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Developer+Testing+using+Maps+and+Expandos+instead+of+Mocks):

```
myController.request = [ getHeader: { -> '0' } ]
```

(that link also includes Expando sample).

If you need extensive Request usage, try [functional-test plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/functional-test).

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's not working. Probably I'm doing it wrong, but I'm a student and new to testing, so my experience and understanding of testing is rather limited. 

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: request for class: WebServiceController

It looks to me as the test expects the property "request" on the controller - this is where I want to step in and want to return the correspending value within my test, and not the controller - i hope you understand my problem

Comment: It should work. I suggest you include some more of the code - at least the test code.